# Starting a service from another foreground Service

Tags: android, foreground

I want to start two different services from one foreground Service, I know its possible to start these types of nested/sub services BUT my main concern here is that the System is more likely to kill a normal service than a foreground service. So if I start a service `mServiceA` from the foreground service `mForegroundService` will the `mServiceA` act as a foreground service in terms of not being killed/destroyed by the system on lower resources ? Since it was initially started through a foreground Service

Comment: "I want to start two different services from one foreground Service" -- why? What is the value in having two services, versus a single service? The point of a service is to indicate that your app is doing work while your main UI is in the background. You do not need more than one service to accomplish that.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I guess I should have added the reason in the question as well, the reason is that I want to create multiple overlays on the screen each service represents an overlay, And yes I know I can add them using a single service as well but due to certain restrictions in the code, I can't, hence the 2 services.

Comment: "I know I can add them using a single service" -- then I recommend doing that. "but due to certain restrictions in the code, I can't" -- perhaps you should be focusing on fixing those restrictions. "my main concern here is that the System is more likely to kill a normal service than a foreground service" -- it's more that on modern versions of Android, you can only run a background service for one minute. That does not change based upon how that background service was started.